# Compute Avg of list value for each element in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, average, neo4j-apoc

The Problem to solve is:

```
List: [x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2] ...[xn, yn, zn]
```

Output expected:

```
[(x1+x2+..+xn)/n, (y1+y2+..yn)/n, (z1+z2+..+z3)/n]
```

`

I'm able to perform the addition when I've 2 list only and size is fixed using the below statement:

```
UNWIND(apoc.coll.zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6])) as output

RETURN COLLECT(apoc.coll.avg(output))
```

Output is

```
[2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
```

But wasn't not able to compyte for dynamic number of *n* list. The size of list is constant for which avg needs to be computed.

**Neo4j Desktop Graph version**: 3.5.18

**APOC LIbrary**: 3.5.0.12

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you pass the list of "sublists" as a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/), `list`, this may work for you:

```
RETURN [w IN
  REDUCE(s = [], sublist IN $list | CASE
    WHEN SIZE(s) = 0 THEN sublist
    ELSE [i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(s)-1) | s[i] + sublist[i]]
    END) |
  w / TOFLOAT(SIZE($list))] AS result
```

`REDUCE` is used to generate a single list with the sums of the corresponding sublist elements.

Comment: Thanks @cybersam. It worked like a charm! Just wanted to update on how to use parameters in Neo4j. `:param list => [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]` for further reference.

Comment: `:param` is a command specific to the neo4j Browser. The way that you would pass a parameter depends on the API or tool that you use to execute the Cypher.