# Neo4j vector operations on arrays

Tags: vector, neo4j, sum, aggregation

I have a graph database where each `Sentence` node has an `embeddings` property which is an array of length 768. What I want to do is create a property in each of these node which is an aggregation of average of all the neighboring nodes' `embeddings`.

Basically,

```
for each node in the graph:
    sum = [0] * 768
    count = 0
    for neighbour in node.neighbours:
        sum = vector_sum(sum, neighbour.embeddings)
        count += 1
    avg = sum / count
    node.neighbours_average = avg
```

Currently, I'm using neomodel to read in the nodes, perform this in python and then ingest it into the graph. Understandably, it is pretty slow.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

I've looked at Data Science Library, APOC, etc, but none of these have vector operations.

Comment: this could probably be solved with cypher and APOC, but would need an example data to code as doing it from the top of my mind is a bit much. You could also add a feature request to APOC for vector operations.

Comment: In cypher, you can use reduce to compute the average of your embeddings as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450549/compute-avg-of-list-value-for-each-element-in-neo4j/62455687?noredirect=1#comment110472903_62455687

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this with the following query:

Note: `embedding` is an array of floats

```
match (s:Sentence)-[r:RELATED]-(t:Sentence)
with s as sentence, collect(t.embedding) as neighbours_embeddings
set sentence.neighbour_avg = [
  w in reduce(
    s=[], neighbour_embedding IN neighbours_embeddings | 
    case when size(s) = 0 then neighbour_embedding
    else [
      i in range(0, size(s)-1) |
      s[i] + neighbour_embedding[i]
    ] end) |
    w / tofloat(size(neighbours_embeddings))
]
```