# Calculate frequency embedding according to an attribute of one-hop neighbouring nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph as follows.
[image]

There are two types of nodes: `A` and `B`.
Node labeled A has property `id`. Node labeled B has property `State`. Suppose `State` can only belong to `[good, bad, average]`.

How can I produce frequency embedding for nodes A using cypher? For example, `A1` should have an attribute  `embedding = [2,0,0]` while `A2` should have `embedding = [2,0,1]`?

Comment: can you explain the problem more precisely? Do the states have a temporal component? Why do you want to embed the list of states in the blue nodes? Do the blue and orange nodes have a label? What is the downstream use of the list of states?

Comment: Hi @DavidAStumpf , there are no temporal components. I want to have the frequency on blue nodes to be able to apply knn algorithm. The blue nodes have label 'A' and orange nodes have label 'B'. Neo4j provides OneHotEncoding in GDS library, but it's not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
Match(n:A)-->(t:B)
WITH collect(t.state) AS state, n
WITH [val IN state WHERE val = "good"] AS good, [val IN state WHERE val = "average"] AS avg, [val IN state WHERE val = "bad"] AS bad, n
WITH size(good) as goodCount, size(avg) as avgCount, size(bad) as badCount, n
SET n.embedding = [goodCount, badCount, avgCount]
return n.key, n.embedding
```

This finds all `A`s and their `B`s, collecting the `B`s state into a list and then create different lists for each state. Next we get the size of each state list and `SET` the `embedding` value according to the order. Last part is to return the `embedding` of the `A`s.

You can check it on this sample data:

```
MERGE (a:A{key: 1})
MERGE (b:A{key: 2})
MERGE (c:B{key: 3, state: 'good'})
MERGE (d:B{key: 4, state: 'good'})
MERGE (e:B{key: 5, state: 'average'})
MERGE (f:B{key: 6, state: 'good'})
MERGE (g:B{key: 7, state: 'good'})

MERGE (a)-[:HAS]-(c)
MERGE (a)-[:HAS]-(d)
MERGE (b)-[:HAS]-(e)
MERGE (b)-[:HAS]-(f)
MERGE (b)-[:HAS]-(g)
```

- using `key` instead of `id`.

It returns:

```
╒═══════╤═════════════╕
│"n.key"│"n.embedding"│
╞═══════╪═════════════╡
│1      │[2,0,0]      │
├───────┼─────────────┤
│2      │[2,0,1]      │
└───────┴─────────────┘
```

If you have many state options, you can do something like:

```
MATCH(n:A)-->(t:B)
WITH apoc.coll.indexOf(["good", "bad", "average"], t.state) as inx, n, [0,0,0] as k
WITH apoc.coll.set(k, inx, 1) AS k, n
WITH collect(k) as kk, n
WITH REDUCE(s = [], sublist IN kk | CASE
    WHEN SIZE(s) = 0 THEN sublist
    ELSE [i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(s)-1) | s[i] + sublist[i]]
    END) AS result, n
SET n.embedding = result
RETURN n.key, n.embedding
```

inspired by [this answer by @cybersam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450549/compute-avg-of-list-value-for-each-element-in-neo4j)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.
But the graph structure above is just an example. In my real graph, the cardinality of states is more than 10 (here it's 3: good, average, and bad), so the query becomes lengthy. 
Is there a way to use a for loop to go over all the state values?

Comment: Answer was edited to include scale

Answer (score 1):

To scale this up to more state categories, we can build on Nimrod's solution.

set up a ref node set with your categories:

```
create (n1:ref{name:'good',order:1})
create (n2:ref{name:'bad',order:2})
create (n3:ref{name:'average',order:3})
```

then the query becomes

```
match (c:ref) 
with c order by c.order
with collect(c.name) as cn
MATCH(n:A)-->(t:B)
WITH apoc.coll.indexOf(cn, t.state) as inx, n, [0,0,0] as k
WITH apoc.coll.set(k, inx, 1) AS k, n
WITH collect(k) as kk, n
WITH REDUCE(s = [], sublist IN kk | CASE
    WHEN SIZE(s) = 0 THEN sublist
    ELSE [i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(s)-1) | s[i] + sublist[i]]
    END) AS result, n
SET n.embedding = result
RETURN n.key, n.embedding
```

or you could start the query as

```
with ['good','bad', 'average'] as cn
```

in either case, you'd add as many categories as needed